# How to change Itextsharp fonts for ShowTextAligned

Tags: c#, itext

I try to change font for a line in creation of PDF but no results. Joke is the color changes, sry if it is some stupid mistake.

I have tried different approaches from the googeling spree.

```
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
pdfContentByte.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(bf, 15);


pdfContentByte.BeginText();
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(ProjNr), 60, 130, 0);
pdfContentByte.EndText();
```

I just want to change fonts for different type of texts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code mixes API levels.

Where you call `PdfContentByte` methods directly, you are working on the lowest API level, writing instructions directly into the page content stream.

Where you call `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned`, on the other hand, you are at a medium API level. At this level iText classes (like `ColumnText`) create all the required instructions in the underlying page content stream themselves; actually your directly written instructions interfere with the instructions written by `ColumnText` and result in invalid instruction sequences.

You really should remain at one API level at a time until you know exactly what you are doing. I propose you use the medium level, not the low level.

In that case you combine the `BaseFont`, the font size, and the text color into a `Font` object, add this font to the `Phrase` object, and then let iText do all the work:

```
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(bf, 15, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);

ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(ProjNr, font), 60, 130, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, also very well explained !